# How to add flash message when user clicks sign out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display flash message when user clicks 'sign out' button. This message should stand for 3 to 5 seconds (`setTimeout`) and then the user would will be signed out. I hope that you understand me.

```js
$('#logout').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault().innerHTML = "You will be logout!";
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "/logout";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="/logout" id="logout">Sign out</a></li>
```

So far this is my code, when user clicks sign out and alert message would be displayed and after 3-5 second user will be sign out. Any idea how to do it? Thank you all.

Comment: clicking on the link you get the following error:  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined".

Comment: `e.preventDefault(); $(this).innerHTML = "You will be logout!";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set the property `innerHTML` of the return value of `preventDefault`. Either append the message to the body, a specific element, or create a new one.

This will show a simple Modal, for more advanced Modals, please refere [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp)

```js
$('#logout').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).hide();
  $("body").append('<div style="z-index: 100; position: fixed; top: 10px; margin: 0 auto; left: 0; right: 0; width: 200px; padding: 20px; background: #EEEEEE;">You will be logged out</div>');
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "/logout";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="/logout" id="logout">Sign out</a></li>
```

Comment: Can I add modal with message: "You will be logged out"

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: Thank you, very much, you saved me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I've corrected your code to use the `jquery` selector `$(this)` and the `.text()` function. I've also corrected the text a little.

Let me know if this wasn't what you wanted.

---

## Demo

```js
$('#logout').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).text("You will be logged out!");
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "/logout";
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="/logout" id="logout">Sign out</a></li>
```